# Upgrade Thunderbird?

Tags: upgrade, thunderbird

I'm having a new problem sending some emails with pdf attachments in Thunderbird. I get a message saying there's an esmtp protocol deviation and the email doesn't go.

I see that I have Thunderbird v 78, but that there's a v 91 available from Thunderbird itself.

Maybe the new version would solve my problem.

Should I upgrade to v 91 now in hopes that it will solve my problem, rather than wait for Ubuntu to do it?

Comment: I have Thunderbird 78 and it sends out pdfs just fine. Do you get an error message that is listed [here](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/smtp-and-esmtp-error-code-list/)?

Comment: Yes. When I turned on logging and tried to send an attachment that wouldn't go earlier, it still wouldn't go and the code I got was 421.

Comment: 421 suggests that this specific mailbox was not enabled. Does it matter which email address you send it to?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. It doesn't matter to which email address I try to send.

Answer (score 1):

You could install the newer Thunderbird as a snap. Version 91.1.1 is in the latest/candidate channel. Such installation can co-exist with your current version.

It can be doubted whether the problem sending a PDF attachment is due to Thunderbird, and to that specific version, however. It is not expected that upgrading will solve that issue.